# Is it possible to overload a method in a class which implements an Interface?

Tags: java, class, interface, overriding, implementation

I have this interface:

```
public interface Library {
    public abstract void addEmployee (Employee employee);
}
```

Three classes implements this interface:

```
public class CentralLibrary extends Store implements Library {
    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee, char determiner) {

    }
}

public class LibraryA extends CentralLibrary implements Library  {
    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {

    }
}

public class LibraryB extends CentralLibrary implements Library  {
    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to override `addEmployee` method with different signature?

Comment: You cannot override with a different signature. That defeats the purpose of overriding!! Excepting return type covariance of course.

Comment: You will need to change the addEmplyee method to match the signature. You should only need to have it into the CentralLibrary class. Also, I don't think you need abstract in an interface.

Comment: If `CentralLibrary` needs a determiner, but the other two don't, they aren't the same type of object.  That means LibraryA and LibraryB shouldn't extend `CentralLibrary`.  If `CentralLibrary` *can* have a determiner, but doesn't require it, then you should just remove the `@Override`, because it doesn't override, it just adds a method to `CentralLibary`

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding, you are overloading. For this, you'll have to add `char determiner` as second argument in the method signature in interface

Comment: But, `LibraryA` and `LibraryB` doesn't need the `char determiner`!

Comment: @Mehran Then you need two methods in the interface. one with only employee argument and the other with the additional char determiner argument